# What is the best way to scroll to something smoothly with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i'm new to coding, like 2 months or something. I'm trying to make a menu in a one-page-website that when you click a link in the menu, you go to that section.. but i don't think this is the best way. that's my javascript code:

```
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.js-menu a[href^="#"]');
function smoothScroll(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const linkTo = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    const section = document.querySelector(linkTo);
    section.scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth",
    })
  }
  menu.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", smoothScroll);
  });
```

and thats my html code:

```
<nav class="menu js-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#animais">Animais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

if you guys have any tips for beginners i would also appreciate it!

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery? (There's some pre-written stuff using jQuery)

Comment: @cssyphus I don't think it's good to advise use of a library when the OP hasn't tagged it.

Comment: _"i don't think this is the best way"_ - why? What makes you think this? Are you looking for opinions? Or is something not working?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think you should let the OP answer that question rather than deciding for him. Given that jQuery is used on over 80% of websites, it is a valid question. If the OP is a beginner, he just might not be aware of jQuery. OTOH, he might just be focussed on learning pure javascript, in which case his answer would be "no". I'd let him answer for himself.

Comment: The best native one is still window.scroll() but that one is fully supported for all browsers yet. scrollIntoView can give some problems when there is an outer scroll.

Comment: @cssyphus I don't think I decided anything. In my mind at least, the lack of a tag is an indicator. I wouldn't recommend the OP use react.

Comment: @cssyphus i'm open to it, of course, but since i'm still learning javascript i was thinking that "pure javascript" it's the best way to learn.. am i wrong?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes i'm looking for opinions! its working normally, but i think i'm "improvising" lol maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: What do _you_ mean by better? I consider using `scrollIntoView` to be a fine way to do this. @JensIngels has already pointed out that it may not work on every device.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#faq').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`

Comment: @JensIngels what do you mean by outer scroll?

Comment: @evolutionxbox a simpler way i think?

Comment: No, not really. The answers below may work more consistently, but they're not simpler

Comment: @evolutionxbox i agree. thanks for helping :)

Comment: @epascarello that code didn't work here. dont know why

Comment: Your code works, just tested it out in chrome. You are saying it does not work?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ - If you don't do this with CSS you need to handle changing the focus as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using CSS, or Js for cross-browser, as shown at the link bellow.

it looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asphttps://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

Comment: it looks interesting. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified SmoothScrolling example taken from w3schools that uses jQuery. Note that a common problem with smooth-scroll (or with jump-to-ID) is that the stop location is a little above or below what is truly desired. The fix is to use an offset, demonstrated in this example. *(View the example "Full Page" by clicking that link at top right of the snippet window)*

```js
$("nav ul li a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        var myOffset = $('#myOff').val(); //get value from input (offset value)
        if (myOffset==='') $('input').addClass('alert');

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        var hash = this.hash; // Store hash
      
        // jQuery animate() method for smooth page scroll
        // 900 is the number of ms to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - myOffset
        }, 900);
    } // End if
});

//$('div:contains(Section)').css('font-weight','bold');
```

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Calibri;}
body{height:2500px;}
ul,li{margin:0;padding:0;}
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
section{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
nav{position:fixed;width:80vw;background:white;border:1px solid red;}
::placeholder{color:#ccc;}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
}
nav ul li:hover{background: #ddd;}
a{text-decoration:none;padding:10px 25px;display:inline-block;}

#one{background:palegreen; padding:50px;}
#two{background:palegoldenrod;}
#twa{background:lightblue;}
#fer{height:1500px;}
.alert{border:1px solid red;background:#ffc0cb99;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>NAV / HEADER:</li>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#twa">Three</a></li>
    <li><input id="myOff" type="text" placeholder="Offset (e.g. 75):" /></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="one">
  <div>
    <div style="text-align:center">Section One</div>
    <div>Directions:<br>(a) View as Full Page (link at top right)<br>(b) Enter offset number (for how many pixels the smooth-scroll will stop short)<br>(c) Click nav "Two" or "Three" and observe<br>(4) Repeat using a different offset value<br>Note: The fixed header is deliberately not full width in order to show the top of the next section scrolling UNDER the header (undesireable) The offset prevents that, and is what you are asking about.</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="two">
  Section Two
</section>
<section id="twa">
  Section Three
</section>
<section id="fer">
  Section Four
</section>
```

Example code ripped off from:

[w3schools Company Theme example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_theme_company_complete_animation)

Comment: thanks :) that problem with the location thing is simpler in with scrollIntoView, because of the block: 'start' thing. but thanks!

Comment: No worries, Rodrigo. If you find a better solution yourself, please post your own answer and select that in order to close out the question and to assist future readers/googlers. Best wishes with your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tags :

on your HTML give a tag to the element that you want to scroll to :

<button (click) = 'scrollto(target)'> CLick ME

> On your JS :
> scrollto (el : HTMLElement)     {
> el.scrollIntoView(true);    }