# CSS scrolling animation when linking to another div?

Tags: html, css

Here is some basic example code: `<a href="#bio">Go to Bio</a>`
This will just take you to the `bio` section of the page. Is
there a way to make a 'scrolling animation' when linking to this
div?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813071/what-is-the-best-way-to-scroll-to-something-smoothly-with-javascrip) to this but the answer involved
JavaScript. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using only
CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

You are looking for:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

[Here is the reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

Comment: Thank you, Igor Bykov! Now I am wondering if there is a way to speed up the scrolling effect, like adding a transition property.

Comment: @Code-Blooded I think currently this is not possible with pure CSS, to implement this you'll need to use JS.

Comment: @Code-Blooded Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it resolved your issue.